# Issue with compiling Python 3.6(tkinter) into exe using cx_Freeze

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, cx-freeze

Here is the code:

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title('Automated Stress Test Analysis')
root.geometry("400x200")

root.mainloop()
```

Here is setup.py:

```
import os
import cx_Freeze
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Python\\Python36-32\\tcl\\tcl8.6"
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Python\\Python36-32\\tcl\\tk8.6"

cx_Freeze.setup( name = "test" , 
options={"build_exe":{"packages":["tkinter"]}}, 
version = "0.1" , 
description = "" , 
executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("test.py")] , )
```

When I run the program in IDE, it would work fine. When I generate the executable, it will be generated. But when I run the executable, a command window will flash and close.

I've tried to add input() to the program but nothing. Then I ran some more test because I think there is a problem with cx_Freeze and tkinter library. I see the issue if I import the library.

I installed cx_Freeze-5.0.2-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl.

Comment: You might want to observe the error first by executing `test.exe` under it's directory in the command line. Else if your os is window, change `executables` in _setup.py_ into `[cx_Freeze.Executable("test.py", base="Win32GUI")] , )`, then it will popup a message box about error.

Comment: `input()` will not work because your exe does not work.  Run it from command prompt and it will show you what the errors are then edit this question to include the error message if you cannot solve it yourself.